# SQL between vs >= startdate and <= enddate

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm writing some SQL queries in PL/SQL that require me to filter the records based on date. The field is a date/time type, but since I don't really care about the time I figured I'll just omit it from my where clause.

So I'm writing something like

```
WHERE
  f.logdate between to_date('2011/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and
                    to_date('2011/01/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

To get all the records for january. I read that this is supposed to be equivalent to

```
WHERE
  f.logdate >= to_date('2011/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and
  f.logdate <= to_date('2011/01/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

But my final results are not what I expected: there are less records when I use the BETWEEN keyword than when I explicitly state the bounds. Is it because my assumption of what BETWEEN does is wrong?

EDIT: ah nvm, it appears that the date is not the issue. There was a subquery that I was using that was filtering its result set by date as well and was specifying date/time while I'm not.

Comment: That looks like how BETWEEN is supposed to work.  Can you reproduce it with a small enough sample that you could post the output, preferably with the full time & date displayed?

Comment: Could you possible have an OR clause in your query that is affecting your order of operations?

Comment: @Bill Unfortunately it seems like even when I reduce it to one day there are still a ton of records.

@PMV: that's the only condition

Comment: Note: you can create dates like: `'2011-1-31'::date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you show the type of the "logdate" field (the sql create sentence could help) ?

In some databases the date type is actually a datetime field, so if you are looking for dates after "Jan 01 2011", you are really looking for dates after "Jan 01 2011 12:00:00 p.m.".

It may be your case.

Comment: You're right, the time was also causing a problem. I have to specify my starting and end time as well.

Answer (score 1):

if the time is set to 0:00 or something strange like that it wont work properly.

```
The query retrieves the expected rows because the date values in the query and the datetime values stored in the RateChangeDate column have been specified without the time part of the date. When the time part is unspecified, it defaults to 12:00 A.M. Note that a row that contains a time part that is after 12:00 A.M. on 1998-0105 would not be returned by this query because it falls outside the range.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer but the question was about Oracle, but you referenced T-SQL documentation.

Comment: True, but often databases work similarly. I thought this might be the case for either.